# não estou conseguindo cadastrar o aluno na lista laluno, quando mostro a lista ela esta vazia

Tags: python-3.x

```
cad = open('cadastro.txt','w')  
aluno = []  
laluno = []  
print("""           OPÇÔES
      1 - cadastrar novo aluno
      2 - listar alunos cadastrados
      3 - buscar aluno
      4 - remover aluno  """)  
 opt = input('Digite uma opção: ')   

def cadastrar_aluno():  
    aluno = str(input("Digite o nome do aluno:"))  
    aluno=aluno.upper()    

def listar_alunos ():   
    print('Alunos Matriculados', laluno)  

if opt == '1':   
   cadastrar_aluno()  
   laluno.append(aluno)  

elif opt == '2':  
    listar_alunos()
```

Comment: A variável `aluno` dentro da função `cadastrar_aluno()` é diferente da `aluno` fora. Alterar esta variável dentro da função não altera ela fora. Tente refazer usando um `return aluno` na função `cadastrar_aluno()` e depois pegando o valor do `return` com `aluno = cadastrar_aluno()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lista está vazia porque após escolher uma opção e preencher com os dados, o programa é encerrado. Faltou você colocar sua lógica dentro de um `while True:` para garantir que o programa só será finalizando quando o usuário solicitar. Naturalmente, é necessário que haja também uma opção para encerrar o programa.

Também, tudo fica mais fácil se você adicionar o aluno à lista dentro da função `cadastrar_aluno`.

Como cortesia, eu modifiquei o seu programa com as observações acima, para você entender melhor. Também removi algumas linhas desnecessárias. Veja como ficou:

```
laluno = []

def cadastrar_aluno():
    aluno = str(input("Digite o nome do aluno: "))
    aluno = aluno.upper()
    laluno.append(aluno)

def listar_alunos ():
    print('Alunos Matriculados:', laluno)

while True:
    print("""           OPÇÕES
        0 - SAIR
        1 - cadastrar novo aluno
        2 - listar alunos cadastrados
        3 - buscar aluno
        4 - remover aluno""")
    opt = input('Digite uma opção: ')

    if opt == '0':
        break
    elif opt == '1':
        cadastrar_aluno()
    elif opt == '2':
        listar_alunos()
```